# How to make kable table reactive() in shiny app? Shiny + kable

Tags: r, shiny, kable, kableextra

I am trying to make kable table reactive and export it in shiny app. already gave a try with `renderDataTable`/`renderTable` inside server and output functions as `datatableOutput`/`tableOutput`, but of no luck and following is the line of code.

```
  output$tableset <- renderDataTable({
kable(spread_bole) %>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 15 ,bootstrap_options = c("striped","hover", "condensed")) })

tableOutput("tableset")
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since `kable` returns HTML, you can render your table using `htmlOutput` in `ui` and `renderText` in `server`:

```
# UI component
htmlOutput("tableset") 

# server component
output$tableset <- renderText({
  kable(spread_bole) %>%
    kable_styling(
      font_size = 15,
      bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed")
    ) 
})
```

Additionally, if you want to make it responsive to user input, you can wrap it in a reactive expression:

```
my_table <- reactive({
  kable(spread_bole) %>%
    kable_styling(
      font_size = 15,
      bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed")
    )
})

# my_table() will call the cached table
```

This will be especially helpful if you want to use the same table multiple times. You can check out `eventReactive` to trigger it with a specific input as well. Please refer here for more information on reactivity in Shiny: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html

Answer (score 2):

Hello was looking for the same and I found [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/use_kable_in_shiny.html) works with a few changes

```
library(shiny)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

data("mtcars"); head(mtcars,2)
mtcars <- rownames_to_column(mtcars, var="car") %>% head


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("mtcars"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("mpg", "mpg Limit",
                  min = 11, max = 33, value = 20)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("mtcars_kable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$mtcars_kable <- function() {
    req(input$mpg)
      mtcars %>%
      #dplyr::mutate(car = rownames(.)) %>% 
      dplyr::select(car, everything()) %>%
      dplyr::filter(mpg <= input$mpg) %>%
      knitr::kable("html") %>%
      kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
      add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 5, "Group 2" = 6))
  }
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]